# Play 2.3: How to count json child nodes?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

I have this json:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "password": [
      "This field is required"
    ],
    "email": [
      "This field is required"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I count child nodes under "errors" node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way, you can do that:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsObject, Json}

val errors = """{"errors":{"password":["This field is required"],"email":["This field is required"]}}"""
val errorsCount = Json.parse(errors).
    asOpt[JsObject].
    flatMap(json => (json \ "errors").asOpt[JsObject]).
    map(json => json.fields.size).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: I copied exact your code and it gives me an error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

Comment: Main cause for the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace“ is: either too many classes or too big classes are being loaded to the Metaspace. You can specify Metaspace explicitly with -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=?m, to solve your problem. I'm running JVM with no additional configurations, so I'm not sure, why it does not work for you.

Comment: I just close and reopen the cmd and it works now. Not sure why. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = {
    "errors": {
        "password": [
            "This field is required"
        ],
        "email": [
            "This field is required"
        ]
    }
};

Object.keys(a.errors).length;
```

Comment: It seem you give javascript code. I use Play Framework in scala.